# Test cases for a Singly Linked list

Tags: testing, linked-list, white-box-testing, black-box-testing

What are some good testcases for a Linked list problem in general? for example test cases for a function which finds and eliminates duplicates and returns the pointer to the first node. Some core cases could be: the function is in c# or Java and not c, c++. Assume all positive integers as nodes of the list.

- Null
- Empty List
- Linked list with a loop
- List with all dups
- List with one node or 2 nodes (2 dups)
- No duplicates
- The list could encounter integer over flow, incase low memory (depending on 32 bit machine, 64 bit machine)
- Security testing, language automation, memory issues, performance and stress

What else? expecting outrageous test cases..any experts out there?

Comment: Since you mentioned that last bullet about Security, Automation, etc, can you tell us more about the context?

Answer (score 6):

How about these?

- traversing the list
- edge cases:

  - traversing an empty list
  - traversing list where 1+ stored values are NULL
- operations (if applicable):

  - deleting from the list
  - inserting into the list
  - inserting a sub-list into the linked list
  - traversing the list backwards (if doubly-linked list)
- concurrency tests (if applicable):

  - race condition tests

Comment: i would also test for lists with one or two nodes as most algos are usually of flavors like saving the next->next and deleting next and son on.

Answer (score 4):

- **Security** -> what level of permission is required to use the API,
  roles etc
- **Memory** - > How much memory is consumed when this API is used; Does it affect performance?
- **Compatibility testing** - > testing the suite using this API on different platforms, windows, MAC, Unix etc.
- **Stress testing** ->  Invoke the API by using a master slave architecture and parallel processing on different clients.
- **UI**-> If the API has a UI, UI test cases come into picture like usability
  testing